# create a i*j struct array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

After searching on the internet, I know how to create a 1*j struct array. For example,

```
>> patient(1).name = 'John Doe';
patient(1).billing = 127.00;
patient(1).test = [79, 75, 73; 180, 178, 177.5; 220, 210, 205];
>> 
>> patient(2).name = 'Ann Lane';
patient(2).billing = 28.50;
patient(2).test = [68, 70, 68; 118, 118, 119; 172, 170, 169];
```

My question is: how to create a j*1 struct array? Thanks so much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

1. You transpose your structure array afterwards:

   `patient = patient';`
2. You index your structure array with two integers (first=row, second=column):

   `patient(j,1).name = 'John Doe';`

Best,

Comment: Here is how you create a struct array with size 2*2.>> patient(1,1).name='AA';
>> patient(2,2).name='B';
>> patient(1,2).name='C';
>> patient(2,1).name='D';
>> patient

patient = 

2x2 struct array with fields:

    name
    billing
    test